# Displaying wrong character in C

Tags: c

I'm testing deciphering strings using a key in standard C. I'm inputting a string, inputting my replacements and constructing a cipher based on the history of my replacements. For example, if I replace c with h in a string, I will store it in the string cipher as `"ch "`, where " denotes the start and end of my string.

My problem is, as I'm trying to run back through my string and revert characters back to their originals, my characters are messing up and showing as heart signs instead. Any insight on this would be much appreciated, I'm sure I'm going wrong somewhere very simple.

```
char from[] = "";
char to[] = "";
for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(cipher); i++){
    if (i == 0){
        from[strlen(from)] = cipher[i];
    }
    else if(cipher[i-1] == ' '){
        from[strlen(from)] = cipher[i];
    }
    else{
        to[strlen(to)] = cipher[i];
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j <= strlen(to); j++){
        if(str[i] == to[j]){
            str[i] = from[j];
        }
    }
}

printf("\nUNSCRAMBLED STRING IS: %s" ,str);
```

cipher is the char array holding my cipher key. to[] hold the second value in the cipher key. from[] holds my first. str is the char array of the string that is to be deciphered.

Comment: amongst many other problems, remember that the index into cipher[] increases 3 bytes per entry, not 1 byte.   Also 'from[] and 'to[] are only 1 byte long and that byte contains a '\0'  so accessing those arrays past index 0 is undefined behaviour and can/will lead to a seg fault event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a number of problems.

(1) One big problem is that you don't have enough storage allocated for `from` and `to` - change:

```
char from[] = "";  // this is equivalent to char from[1] = "";
char to[] = "";
```

to e.g.:

```
char from[256] = "";
char to[256] = "";
```

(where 256 is just some arbitrary size that should be greater than the size of your data set).

(2) You need to terminate your strings properly when you append a character, e.g.

```
if (i == 0){
    from[strlen(from)] = cipher[i];
}
```

should be:

```
if (i == 0){
    int len = strlen(from);
    from[len] = cipher[i];
    from[len + 1] = '\0';
}
```

(3) You're indexing by one too many characters when you iterate through a string, so e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(cipher); i++){
```

should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(cipher); i++){
```

Comment: altered this, using the scrambled string "rdease" and the cipher key "pr ld" the outputted deciphered key is just "p". I am sure there is a problem with my loop but I can't see what it is for the life of me

Comment: Added a couple more problems and fixes now.

Comment: thanks alot! it only appears to mess up now if I use more than one replacement. if my cipher variable only holds 2 characters in it, it deciphers fine. But if I have 2 different replacements, it messes up. Test data: str = "fyease" . cipher = "pf ly " . str after deciphering = "p"

Comment: OK - time to learn how to use your debugger - step through the code inspecting variables as you go - you should soon be able to identify any remaining bugs,